# Split a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, trim

the following code works for me, but seems to be quite long-winded. Can i shorten it?

```
var str = "some title of an event here, weekday 17:00&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;18:00 o’clock, with name of a person";
var date = str.split(', ');
var time = date[1].split(' ');
var timeItems = time[1].split('–');
var startTime = timeItems[0].trim();
var endtime = timeItems[1].trim();
alert("event lasts from "startTime + " to " + endtime);
```

Thanks

Comment: If it works as expected, there's nothing to fix. Move on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is all you want the `startTime` and `endTime`? If so, you could just do `split()` on the colon character:

```
times = str.split(':');
startTime = times[0].slice(-2) + ':' + times[1].slice(0,2);
endTime = times[1].slice(-2) + ':' + times[2].slice(0,2);
alert("event lasts from " + startTime + " to " + endTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

While regexes are often overkill, they will help you here in your quest for shorter code:

```
var str = "some title of an event here, weekday 17:00&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;18:00 o’clock, with name of a person";
var times = str.match(/\d\d?:\d\d/g);
alert("event lasts from " + times[0] + " to " + times[1]);
```

Run it at http://jsfiddle.net/jvs3s/